# System of differential equations 1

Tags: calculus

System of differential equations
Method integrable combinations
$$dx/dt = x^2-2xy $$
$$dy/dt = 2xy-y^2$$  Please help

Comment: I dont understand. I need general solution of this question

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $$\dfrac{dx}{dy}=\dfrac{x^2-2xy}{2xy-y^2}=\dfrac{1-2(y/x)}{2(y/x)-(y/x)^2}$$

And notice that right hand side became a function of $(y/x)$

Comment: i dont understand :(

Comment: @mesel, Respected Mr. mesel, please, provide the detailed (full) solution to this system of differential equations without any hints.